# Is there a way to display user form in IDE instead of host app?

Tags: vba, excel, ide, userform, commandbar

I created a userform in an *.xlam add-in and created a new commandbar and button in the IDE, but when I click the button, the user form is opened in Excel, and focus is forced away from the IDE. Is there a way to open the user form in the IDE instead of the host application without resorting to a .Net COM Add-in?

Here is the code that creates the commandbar and button and handles the button click event.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdBarEvents As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    CreateCommandBar
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Application.VBE.CommandBars("VBIDE").Delete
End Sub

Private Sub CreateCommandBar()

    Dim bar As CommandBar
    Set bar = Application.VBE.CommandBars.Add("VBIDE", MsoBarPosition.msoBarFloating, False, True)
    bar.Visible = True

    Dim btn As CommandBarButton
    Set btn = bar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
    btn.Caption = "Show Form"
    btn.OnAction = "ShowForm"
    btn.FaceId = 59

    Set cmdBarEvents = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(btn)

End Sub

Private Sub cmdBarEvents_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    CallByName Me, CommandBarControl.OnAction, VbMethod

End Sub

Public Sub ShowForm()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

P.S. You may need this line of code to remove the commandbar...

```
Application.VBE.CommandBars("VBIDE").Delete
```

Comment: Yes: make it a [VBE add-in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1942651/1188513) instead of an Excel add-in! ;)

Comment: Do you mean a floating userform which doesn't steal the focus?

Comment: Well, I would like the *userform* to get the focus, without Excel stealing the focus from the IDE. I have no idea if it's even possible @SiddharthRout.

Comment: Ah I understand now what you are trying.

Comment: Do you need Excel Instance Visible at the same time? Can it be hidden while the user is working in VBE and then show it later? I have an idea

Comment: Not necessarily.... I'm happy to hear any ideas @SiddharthRout.

Comment: + 1 For a nice question. I should have been in bed (It's 3:27 AM) but this kept me awake. The challenge of not using `.Net COM Add-in` was just too much :D

Comment: I have added an edit. You may want to refresh the page. I am off to bed. Will look at in the morning if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative.

Put a button on your user form. For demonstration purpose, I am using this

[image]

Next put this code in the userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Next paste this on top of your class module

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Dim Ret As Long, ChildRet As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
```

Finally change your `Sub ShowForm()` to this

```
Public Sub ShowForm()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    Dim Ret As Long

    frm.Show vbModeless

    Application.Visible = False

    Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption)

    SetWindowPos Ret, HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 250, 200, _
    SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW
End Sub
```

This is what you get

[image]

**EDIT**

More thoughts. To prevent the user from creating more userforms when the user clicks on smiley, change the `Sub ShowForm()` to the below. (*Alternative would be to disable the smiley and re enable it when the form unload?*)

```
Public Sub ShowForm()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    Dim Ret As Long
    Dim formCaption As String

    '~~> Set Userform Caption
    formCaption = "Blah Blah"

    On Error Resume Next
    Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", formCaption)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> If already there in an instance then exit sub
    If Ret <> 0 Then Exit Sub

    frm.Show vbModeless
    frm.Caption = formCaption

    Application.Visible = False

    Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption)

    SetWindowPos Ret, HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 250, 200, _
    SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW
End Sub
```

Comment: @RubberDuck: kool :) Gnite!

Comment: +1 for the effort! ...looks *almost* easier to go with a COM add-in though ;)

Comment: @retailcoder: Easier than Com Add-In? Nope. Definitely not. This is way too easy :). Having said that would I prefer a COM Add-In or this? Ummm, it will ultimately depend on what I am trying to do. If it is just a small functionality then I will stay with VBA. I only use Com-Addins when I want to "extend" the functionality of Office applications for custom task. Specially things which I can't handle from VBA.

Comment: Beautiful hack. Thank you! Ultimately I do think the com add-in will be the way to go though. There's a point where we're really just pushing vba past what we should.