# How to write a Add-in for the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications"

Tags: vba, ms-access, add-in

I want to write a Add-In for the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" which I have to use.

I want to add some convenience functions.

Unfortunately I cant find anything about this because as soon as I search for "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" or "Add-In" it tells me how to write Add-in with VBA. But I want to know how I write a Add-In in any language (if possible everything else but vba) for the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications"

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is not an environment, it´s a **language**, similar to C# Java or whatever. You can´t *extend* that, you can however extend an "Integrated Development Environemtn" (IDE), such as Visual Studio by creating an AddIn. Howto do this is well explained on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/80493a3w(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) has served me pretty well for my smaller VBA projects and extended the IDE to everything I needed. It's partly written in C# maybe studying it's source code will help you creating a Add-In?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: The program we use for creating vba-programs for access is definitely called "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications". Its this one: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjs6ubFveTbAhVE2KQKHcmRBuQQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.techonthenet.com%2Fexcel%2Fmacros%2Fimmediate_window2016.php&psig=AOvVaw3134GuhXKnJmGH11aH3XP4&ust=1529661031021683

Comment: @ Freggar: Thank you. This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found the answer to my question.

Here:
https://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx
I found a good description for writing the AddIn in Visual Basic (It was no problem to translate it to C#)

Here:
[Build add-in for VBA IDE using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942626/build-add-in-for-vba-ide-using-vb-net/51288795#51288795)
I found good tipps for troubleshooting.

btw. the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" is called "VBE"