# How to add a custom control to a menubar in an ms-access VBE-Add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-access, vsto, add-in

I wrote an Add-in for the VBA-Editor of MS Aaccess in C# [How to write a Add-in for the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965251/how-to-write-a-add-in-for-the-development-enviroment-microsoft-visual-basic-fo)

I already created a toolbar like this:

```
var toolbar = m_VBE.CommandBars.Add(RadToolbarCaption, MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, System.Type.Missing, true);
```

As I need a more sophisticated control (a dropDown list with icons inside) in the toolbar I thought of adding a custom control to the toolbar. This is what I tried:

```
try
{
    var crtl = m_toolbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlCustom);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

But this returns an ArgumentException:

> Value outside of the valid range 
>   (Original: "Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs.")

Is there a way to add a control other than the few standard controls to the menuebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use non-standard controls in an Office `CommandBar` object.