# How to add a CheckBox to a menubar in an ms-access VBE-Add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-access, vsto, add-in

I wrote an Add-in for the VBA-Editor of MS Access in C# [How to write a Add-in for the development enviroment: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965251/how-to-write-a-add-in-for-the-development-enviroment-microsoft-visual-basic-fo)

I already created a toolbar like this:

```
var toolbar = m_VBE.CommandBars.Add(RadToolbarCaption, MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, System.Type.Missing, true);
```

Now I need a CheckBox or a PushButton (a control which represents a true/false state) in the toolbar

But it seems like there is no checkBox in MsoControlType and I did not find a way to make a Button 'pushable'.

Is there a way to add a CheckBox (or another control which provides the same functionality) to the menubar?

Comment: I very much doubt. Probably have to open a dialog form such as you get with the app Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...it seems like there is no natural way to do this.

So I decided to use a standard button where I toggle the Icon/Text after clicking. This will simulate a push button.